# Image is not shown on the view Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, imagesource

I am trying to show my data after json Deserialization on the web.Every data working perfectly except the Images. It shows only image sign on the web but now the actual images.My Code for controller class in where I deserialized Json object is as follows-

```
public ActionResult PlaceInformation(City objCityModel)
{
    string name = objCityModel.Name;
    ViewBag.Title = name;
    var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/" + name + ".json"));
    RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);
    List<Poi> mycities = new List<Poi>();

    foreach (var item in json.poi)
    {
        Poi obj = new Poi()
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            Shorttext = item.Shorttext,
            GeoCoordinates = item.GeoCoordinates,
            Images = item.Images,

        };
        mycities.Add(obj);
    }

    ViewBag.Cities = mycities;
    return View();
}
```

Now in the view class I want to show every item from this json.But I am having error for images which I mentioned beside code. The error is:

> An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. Parser Error Message: Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character. Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@"

My code is -

```
@model  CallListService.Models.City
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title1 = "Show Data";
}

 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cities)
 {
     <h2>@item.Name</h2>
     <p>@item.Shorttext</p>

     <p>@item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude</p>
     <p>@item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude</p>

    @foreach (var image in item.Images) //Parser Error
    {
        <img src=@image >
    }
}
```

Again if I only write in this way it works but image is not shown, only img sign is shown.

```
<img src=@item.Images>
```

I am not finding any solution for this.

[This is screenshot of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2zDk.jpg)

SourceCode:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>PlaceInformation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div> 

         <h2>Nordertor</h2>
         <p>The Nordertor is an old town gate in Flensburg, Germany, which was built around 1595. Today the landmark is used as a symbol for Flensburg.</p>
         <p>9.43004861</p>
         <p>54.79541778</p>
            <img src="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" />
         <h2>Naval Academy M�rwik</h2>

         <p>9.45944444</p>
         <p>54.815</p>
            <img src="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" />
         <h2>Flensburg Firth</h2>


         </p>
         <p>9.42901993</p>
         <p>54.7959404</p>
            <img src="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" />


   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am using following json file to get all data

```
  {
   "poi":[
    {
      "Name": "Nordertor",
      "Shorttext": "The Nordertor is an old tows used as a symbol for Flensburg.",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
        "Longitude": 9.43004861,
        "Latitude": 54.79541778
      },
      "Images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Nordertor_im_Schnee_%28Flensburg%2C_Januar_2014%29.JPG/266px-Nordertor_im_Schnee_%28Flensburg%2C_Januar_2014%29.JPG"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Naval Academy Mürwik",
      "Shorttext": "The Naval Academy Mürwik is the main training e..",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
        "Longitude": 9.45944444,
        "Latitude": 54.815
      },
      "Images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/MSM-hauptgebaeude.jpg/400px-MSM-hauptgebaeude.jpg"
      ]
    },

    {
      "Name": "Flensburg Firth",
      "Shorttext": "Flensburg Firth or Flensborg Fjordg and the villages Munkbrarup, Langballig, Westerholz, Quern, Steinberg, Niesgrau, Gelting, and Nieby.\n\n",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
        "Longitude": 9.42901993,
        "Latitude": 54.7959404
      },
      "Images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Flensborg_Fjord_ved_bockholmwik.jpg/400px-Flensborg_Fjord_ved_bockholmwik.jpg"
      ]
    }



    ]


}
```

Comment: How is that `<img src=@item.Images>` rendered as html? I mean; what does the output html looks like?

Comment: What parser error do you get on your foreach loop?

Comment: @Stefan. Only the sign. Not the image

Comment: Please post the html output, the `<img src=.... />` thing. Or, if there's even no `<img.../>`, post the html which it produces.

Comment: Inspect that element and see what value you have for src.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: remove the @ from the second for loop.

Comment: @harry.luson So what you have up there should work just fine.  Remove the @ character from before the foreach and see what happens.

Comment: @Stefan I could not understand. Could you please explain a little bit more

Comment: Lol, I missed the error part. Next time, if you have a question, please include all the error messages. The thing about the html: if open the page in a browser and you see just a `-`, as you said, that doesn't tell a lot. Inspecting the html element with dev-tools will reveal the html. That the thing I was asking about

Comment: Btw,  the `<img src=@item.Images>` should be like: `<img src="@item.Images"/>`

Comment: @Becuzz I remove @ charecter. But the problem is not solved

Comment: @harry.luson: same error?

Comment: @Stefan if I write in this way it shows a sign of a image but not the images

Comment: Ok, then again; please show us the html.

Comment: @Stefan Ok I am giving the Screenshot. just a moment

Comment: Wait; this is what I mean, the source code of the website: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm

Comment: @Stefan: I gave it in my question

Comment: Go to your page, right-click it and select `show source`, search for the `<img>` and post it here as html. That source is the html and is not in your question.  If you follow that procedure we can answer your question :-)

Comment: @Stefan Oh. Sorry for misunderstanding. Yes I modified my question and gave source code

Comment: What is the exact Parse Error Message ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound. I found the solution and choose the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the inner loop to:

```
foreach (var image in item.Images) //without the `@`
{
    <img src="@image" />  //with " and />
}
```

This should work if the specified file exists. (if it doesn't work, show the full error + html :-)

Answer (score 1):

Image tag will always expect path for that image

```
<img src="./images/name.jpg" />
```

or

```
<img src="http:/wwww.sitename.com/images/name.jpg" />
```

what does you Image contain image path or image byte?

if it contain image byte then it has to be rendered separately by creating an intermediate page

Comment: I am using url image. so image directly come from url

Comment: can you please right click on that image and provide me the path which is getting added **OR** can you check the view source of the image html which is getting generated

Comment: Hi I got all these images from json file. Ok I am adding my json file on the question.

Comment: Right click on your page and click on **View Source** and give me the HTML code generated in background

Comment: I added this View Source in my question

Comment: Put `<img src='@item.Images'>` or `<img src="@item.Images">` and run your code again